# Helper `@Html.EditorFor` is displaying a value of another field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, editorfor

In my application, for some reason, the URL field is displayed the value of another field.

I believe it is displaying the value of the field `Palavra chave`

**I did some tests:**

```
<div>
    <p>Normal: @Model.Url</p>
    <p>Display : @Html.DisplayFor(p => p.Url)</p>
    <p>Editor : @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Url)</p>
    <p>Editor2 : @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Url, "Url")</p>
    <p>TextBox : @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Url)</p>
    <p>TextBox2 : @Html.TextBox("test", Model.Url)</p>
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Name)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(p => p.UrlKeyword)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.UrlKeyword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.UrlKeyword)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
   -> @Html.LabelFor(p => p.Url)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(p => p.Url)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Url)
</div>
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78i21.png

As you can see the value of the field is correct!

**ProjectViewMode.cs**

```
[Display(Name = "Palavra chave")]
public string UrlKeyword { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Url)]
[Display(Name = "Link")]
public string Url { get; set; }
```

**Project**

[image: Project solution]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v8pd.png

**Thank you all for any help!**

Comment: What is the difference between DisplayNameFor vs labelFor?